# Dual monitor setup issue - Both monitors are detected but second screen Is blank/black

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I recently bought a new monitor for my PC... and I have a big problem.

I connected 2 monitors to my graphic card: Geforce GTX 1050.
One with HDMI and the second one with a DVI adapter. 
They are both detected by the computer but the second monitor is blank/black.

The monitor that is not working is a Samsung S24F350

PICTURES:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
[image: pic5]
[image: pic6]
[image: pic7]

When I plug the HDMI into the second monitor he displays everything just fine but with the DVI he is only detected and not displaying...

Answer (score 0):

Is your Display displaying "Check Signal Cable" or anything like that?

If not, seeing as your graphicscard is detecting a monitor my best guess is that you have to switch your monitor source to analog/D-SUB.

<strike>It also could be that you are using a wrong DVI-Cable/Adapter (Please check if your DVI-Cable is Dual Link). *(I'm not 100% sure on that point).*</strike>

If you want a easy non-fix solution, you could buy a Displayport-HDMI Cable and use your monitor that way.

Comment: Can you please help me to fix it? Maybe do you have discord? My discord: VorT3eX#2722

Comment: Sorry my cable is not "Check Signal cable" or anything else, My screen is just black and i am on analog

Comment: Hello, yes I have Discord. Please send me a direct link? I don't know what to do with "VorT3eX#2722 "

Comment: What is your discord name?

Comment: I need to add you, Your discord name have to be with #4numbers